# Mediawiki doesn't send any email

Tags: php, mail, sendmail, mediawiki

My mediawiki installation (1.28.0, PHP 7.0.13) doesn't send any email and yet there is no error emitted. I checked using Special:EmailUser page.

What I have tryed: 
1) A simple PHP script to send a mail using PHP's mail() function. It works.
2) I have turned PHP mail log. There is a normal line for each Mediawiki email "sent".

PHP is configured (correctly since it works) to send email using Linux SendMail.
MediaWiki is *not* configured to use direct SMTP.

Any suggestion appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Related discussion : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42398213/mediawiki-doesnt-send-any-email

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was not in MediaWiki. It was in an email filter located on the receiving side. That filter catch emails sent by MediaWiki but not email sent by my simple PHP test script.

I was able to confirm MediaWiki correctly send the email by using TcpDump to capture network traffic on port 25 and look at the capture packets using WireShark.

To capture packets, I used to command line:

```
tcpdump -i ens33 -s 65535 -w mail.pcap port 25
```

- `ens33` is the name of the ethernet interface used for sending the mail.

The I can open mail.pcap using WireShark.

I have done two captures: one for my test mail script and one with a mail sent by MediaWiki using Special:EmailUser page. Then comparing the two captures showed that both emails were correctly sent. I then started to investigate at the receiving side to eventually find the offending email filtering rule.

I would like to thanks Alex and Wakalaka who helped me a lot commenting the same question I asked there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42398213/mediawiki-doesnt-send-any-email

Regards